# Checkbox within a ListView

Tags: android, listview, checked

I wish to populate a listview which contains checkbox as list items in an android application. I have implemented a listview, but if I check anyone of the checkboxes in the list it checks some other lists in the listview.. Thanks in advance..

For custom Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/check_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For the listview:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

For Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ListHolder holder;
    row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ListHolder();
        holder.chk = (CheckBox) row
            .findViewById(R.id.chk_check);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ListHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    if (list != null) {
        String data = list.get(position);
        holder.chk.setText(data);

    }

    return row;
}

public class ListHolder {

    CheckBox chk;
}
```

All are working fine, but the checkboxes checked itself when I scroll the listview.

Comment: please show your codes

Comment: It might be happened because of the core refreshing the listview when we scroll..

Comment: you are supposed to maintain and change the checked status of the checkbox your self, otherwise the view recycling gives you checked view that stay checked.

Comment: Yeah its working so.. Got the source of the problem, will solve it soon..